# How to implement a color picker instead of static colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, color-picker

I am developing a painting website. I have a script for selecting colors. It is working fine till now.

Here is the code to selecting my colors.

```
<div class="colorpick">
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(150, 0, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 152);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(0, 151, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 5);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(0, 255, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(255, 150, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 150);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(0, 255, 150);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(150, 0, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
  <div class="pick" style="background-color:rgb(0, 150, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>
</div>
```

The colors are shown as

[image]

This is the code to my **function hello()**

```
<script>
  function hello(e){
    var rgb = e.replace(/^(rgb|rgba)\(/,'').replace(/\)$/,'').replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
    myColor.r = parseInt(rgb[0]);
    myColor.g = parseInt(rgb[1]);
    myColor.b = parseInt(rgb[2]);
    curColor = myColor;
    console.log(curColor);
  }
</script>
```

But I want to implement a color picker. I have the script for color picker as well.

```
<input type="color" value="#ffffff" onchange="clickColor(0, -1, -1, 5)" id="html5colorpicker">
```

**MY QUESTION IS THAT:** How can I integrate color picker with my current code? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Off the top of my head (and this is not a complete solution) you could use 3 sliders... Red green and blue. And then have a box showing the current color as the sliders are updated

Comment: I have a section with static colors. I just want to make it like color picker. And not static section.

Comment: visit this link http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You can use `spectrum.js` along with jquery ui for implementing colorpicker.

HTML:

```
<h2>Basic Usage</h2>
<input type='text' class="basic"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
        $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/ctkY3/)**

http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js 
http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css

Comment: Let me have a look at it.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the implementation of the `clickColor` method which is the method that gets called after the color is changed from the html5colorpicker.

Something like that:

```
function clickColor(){
    var hexColorString = document.getElementById('html5colorpicker').value;
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hexColorString);
    if(result){
        myColor.r = parseInt(result[1], 16);
        myColor.g = parseInt(result[2], 16);
        myColor.b = parseInt(result[3], 16);
    }  
    curColor = myColor;
    console.log(curColor);
}
```

The script assumes that `myColor` and `curColor` are already defined with global scope.

Also remember to change that line to match the new clickColor definition:

`<input type="color" value="#ff0000" onchange="clickColor()" id="html5colorpicker">`

You can change the default color by changing the `value` attribute of the input